# How to get input from function with 'self' as variable

Tags: python, function, self

I want a function where you can enter a string and this string can be reused in the class. This is what I tried but I can't get the `variable` global to use it outside the `function` in the `class`

test.py

```
from Moduletest import Test


Test().set_string("Hello")
```

Moduletest.py

```
class Test():   

    def set_string(self, target_string):
        global string
        string = target_string
        print(string)
    
    zeta = string
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish or what's your question.

Comment: I want that the variable zeta takes the value of the variable string or in this case `"Hello"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To manipulate the static variable defined in the test class, you can review the application below. In this way, you can observe the differences between the data member and the static variable.

```py
class Test:
    zeta = ""                                      # static variable definition
    
    @classmethod                                   # constructor method
    def __init__(self, string):
        self.string = string
    
    @classmethod                                   # member method
    def getString(self):
        return self.string
    
    @classmethod                                   # member method
    def setString(self, value):
        self.string = value
        
    @staticmethod                                  # static method
    def set_static_string(self, target):
        self.setString(target)                     # set data member
        Test.zeta = target                         # set static variable
        
firstTestObject = Test("test")                     # create object
Test.set_static_string(firstTestObject, "first")   # set static variable
print("1: ", Test.zeta)                            # get static variable
print("2: ", firstTestObject.zeta)                 # get static variable

secondTestObject = Test("test")                    # create object
Test.set_static_string(secondTestObject, "second") # set static variable
print("3: ", Test.zeta)                            # get static variable

# The same value is printed as static variables are common to every object.
print("4: ", firstTestObject.zeta)                      
print("5: ", secondTestObject.zeta)
```

This application produces the following output:

```
1:  first
2:  first
3:  second
4:  second
5:  second
```

Comment: Is it not possible to use the input inside the class?

Comment: To use the static variable in the class, simply write `Test.zeta`. This expression works as both `rvalue` and `lvalue`.

Comment: Yes worked thank you. Didn't knew that the var will be saved in my Core.py 
Had to fix some other bugs but it worked finally thank you :D

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to use the global modifier here. What you need, is to reference to the object instance by using the `self` object like so:

```
class Test:
    zeta = None
    def __init__(self):
        self.string = None

    def set_string(self, target_string):
        self.string = target_string
        print(self.string)
        Test.zeta = self.string

t = Test()
t.set_string('abc')
```

Comment: But is it not possible to use t.set_string('abc') outside the class and use 'abc' in the class ? I mean outside the `def set_string`

Answer (score 1):

Making a variable global in python is usually strongly discouraged. I would suggest using an instance of your class and then assigning the string to an attribute of that class.

```
class Test:
    my_string: str

    def__init__(self, target_string):
        self.my_string = target_string
    
    def get_string(self):
        return self.my_string
```

Then you can access `my_string` like this

```
my_class = Test('Hello World')
the_string = my_class.get_string()
print(the_string) # Prints 'Hello World'
# Or like this 
print(my_class.my_string) # Prints 'Hello World' as well
```

When asking a question on here please be descriptive as to what you are trying to achieve. In this instance you should specify why you are trying to make the string global, so that others can possibly recommend alternatives, or have a better understanding of the question.

**Updated per the OP's comment**:
In python there are rarely use cases for using global variables. Instead of storing the string as a global var, I would suggest storing the string as a class instance variable. You can read more on class instance variables [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables).

```
class Test:
    my_string: str
    
    # You could use a dunder init method like this
    def __init__(self, target_string):
        """ This is the function that is ran upon Invoking the 
            class as an instance """
        self.my_string = target_string

    # Or you could not use the dunder init method and just have a class method like this. 
    # This way of doing so is not recommended though
    def set_string(self, target_string):
        """ Sets class instance variable 'mystring' to that of the 'target_string' parameter """
        self.my_string = target_string

# Then to set and retrieve the string from the class instance

# If using the __init__ method
tester_cls = Test('I am the target string')

print(tester_cls.my_string) # Prints 'I am the target string'

# or if using the set_string method
tester_cls = Test()
tester_cls.set_string('I am the target string')

print(tester_cls.my_string) # Prints 'I am the target string'
```

Comment: I wanted to use the input I get from the function inside the class and assign it to a variable outside `def set_string(self, target_string):`

Comment: I've updated my answer to account for your question. Please note that using global variables can/should be avoided when possible

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to do this in **Moduletest.py**:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, target_string):
        self.string = target_string
    
    def getStr(self):
        return self.target_string
```

And then in the **main.py**:

```
from Moduletest import Test

x = Test("Hello")
print(x.getStr) #output: Hello
```

Comment: You can add a method called setStr for easier use (but you can technically reuse the variable name and reassign it a value using the constructor).

Answer (score 0):

Self is the variable where you reference variables for functions inside your instantiated class.

The way to instantiate your class and pass an argument using the constructor is like this.

```
 `class Test:`

      `def __init__(self,arg1)`

          `self.var1 = arg1`
```

You instantiate the class Test like this `my_instance=Test("my_string")`

You access var1 via `.` like this.  `my_instance.var1`

Read the manual here https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html